# Open XML iterated table binding to word document

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I have to bind iterated tables to word document using open xml. I.I can able to bind single table to word document.[image: Word final view]

i am able to bind single table header 1 shown in image using book mark.

Could you please provide some ideas to bind multiple tables dynamically.Here in above image header 1 ,header 2 are dynamic ..IT may goes until header N..

Can any one provide some ideas to how to proceed on this .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this -

```
foreach(HeaderPart headerPart in docGenerated.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
    {
        foreach(Table table in headerPart.Header.Descendants<Table>())
        {
            // do whatever you want to do with your table.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not this.Tables are dynamic.i found few options to do this.Iterated content controls are content controls.Still i am working on work around for this.